# Present JSON string in sorted order from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, sorting

I made one JSON string from the `NSDictionary`. The JSON string which I created doesn't come present the items in the order I entered keys and value pair in the `NSDictionary` .

Now I need all keys and value pairs returned as JSON string in alphabetic order. I tried lot of ways but not getting sorting of JSON string in alphabetic order.

Here's an example of the way the final string is being presented:

```
{
    "SubscriberID" : "603",
    "Amount" : "1",
    "MerchantID" : "100012",
    "Channel" : "Wallet",
    "RequestCode" : "0331",
    "PosID" : "0465F35F5577CUST",
    "TID" : "0000014",
    "Stan" : "NA"
}
```

How do I ensure the items are presented the way I entered them? Or how can I specify the items are alphabetically sorted?

Comment: You cannot sort the entries in a JSON "object".  By definition the order is "undefined".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're misinterpreting the symptoms.  Likely the SHA algorithm is being applied slightly differently or one of you is checking against an escaped or Base64 encoded version and the other isn't.  It makes absolutely no sense to decode the received JSON string and *then* do the checksum.

Answer (score 4):

SBJson is able to do this, set sortKeys to YES on SBJsonWriter

http://superloopy.io/json-framework/

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
writer.sortKeys = YES;
// Turn on humanReadable if you also need it pretty-printed
// writer.humanReadable = YES;
NSData *result = [writer dataWithObject:myDictionary];
```

Comment: But that's not standard JSON, and no network protocol should rely on it.

Comment: @HotLicks Why does the fact that the keys are sorted suddenly make it "not standard JSON"? Does being a square prohibit it from also being a rectangle?

Comment: *Requiring* that the keys be sorted makes it not standard JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Like many key-value storage classes, `NSDictionary` does not guarantee order of the elements you've added. It is a mistake to assume that the key/value pairs, or keyset, will be returned with any particular order.

Further, JSON objects are unordered in the same fashion. You should not care about the order in which the objects are added. Nor should you (or your recipient) rely on being *provided* a JSON object with 'sorted' keys, as that's not really a valid concept with these particular structures. While ordering the keys might result in an iterator traversing the keys in the order you expect, it's not a guarantee, and should *not* be relied on.

I think you should revisit **why** you need the keys sorted in the first place, and see if you can find a way to avoid a dependency on their alphabetical ordering.

**Edit:** You mention the server *requires* an SHA hash of the JSON string. If you must, you can create a sorted JSON string by sorting the keys in an `NSMutableArray`, then creating the JSON string from those keys.

```
NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myDict allKeys]]; 
[sortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSMutableString *jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[jsonString appendString:@"{"];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    [jsonString appendFormat:@"\"%@\"", key];
    [jsonString appendString:@":"];
    [jsonString appendFormat:@"\"%@\"", [myDict objectForKey:key]];
    [jsonString appendString:@","];
}
if ([jsonString length] > 2) {
    [jsonString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([jsonString length] - 1, 1)];
}
[jsonString appendString:@"}"];
```

This code hasn't been tested, so you might need to play with it a bit. Thought it would be much better if you could find a JSON library to do this for you, although you might not have as much control over the key ordering.

Comment: Actually i need to make SHA256 of this string , which is generating different from the server. Because server is using alphabetic JSON string

Comment: You're creating an SHA hash of a JSON string? Why, does the server require it? If so, perhaps you could post code showing what you're sending to the server?

Comment: I'm working with secure server , where i need to make SHA256 , then taking HEXA value from SHA256 and passing that value to server

Comment: @Prateeksharma - The JSON *string* will not change order during transmission.  You can create a checksum on the string, verify it against the string on the other end, and reliably have it verify. Just don't convert the string into "native" objects first.

Comment: @HotLicks I think maybe he has to send the SHA hash *along* with the JSON string, so the server can ensure that it received what the client sent. Since he has to generate the hash, he has to find a way to duplicate the method the server is using, I suppose. To the OP: See my updated code snippet.

Comment: @HotLicks yes i have to create a checksum , in server end , checksum is created for the hexa value and same I'm doing . But they are generating hexa value of string in alphabetic order and mine gets changed

Comment: Are you generating the checksum on the JSON *string* or on objects before sending?  Is the receiving end checking the JSON *string* or is it checking the decoded objects?  Are you both checking the same representation?  Ie, if you're checking a Base64 or escaped version of the string, is the other end doing the same?

Comment: (What do you mean "checksum is created for the hexa value"?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it (or at least you can't rely on that). JSON objects are *unordered* sets as you can read on [JSON.org](http://json.org).

Comment: Can you share direct link , where it is mentioned that we can't do sorting of JSON string. As i don't see any line there showing "Sorting is not possible on JSON string"

Comment: `An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.` it's in the page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,the system method [NSString stringWithFormat:] is what you need.So here is the easy way:

```
NSDictionary* inputDictionary = @{
            @"SubscriberID" : @"603",
            @"Amount" : @"1",
            @"MerchantID" : @"100012",
            @"Channel" : @"Wallet",
            @"RequestCode" : @"0331",
            @"PosID" : @"0465F35F5577CUST",
            @"TID" : @"0000014",
            @"Stan" : @"NA"
            };
NSString* sortedJsonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", inputDictionary];
NSLog(@"sorted json string is %@", sortedJsonStr);
```

The result is:

```
{
    Amount = 1;
    Channel = Wallet;
    MerchantID = 100012;
    PosID = 0465F35F5577CUST;
    RequestCode = 0331;
    Stan = NA;
    SubscriberID = 603;
    TID = 0000014;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The question does not make sense, and therefore cannot be answered in its current form.

If you encode some JSON as `{"keyB":"valueB","keyA":"valueA"}`, take it's checksum, and then transmit the encoded JSON and the checksum to the remote site, the remote site has little choice but to take the checksum of the JSON as received and compare that.  To do the checksum on sorted values it would have to decode the received JSON string into an NSDictionary, re-encode into "sorted" JSON, and *then* take the checksum of the reconstituted JSON, and that would be a lot of extra effort for no reason.

Far more likely is that there is some difference in either the way the checksum is being computed (padding of the SHA256 input, eg) or some difference in the JSON strings being used -- code page differences, escaped characters, one end is doing it on Base64 and the other not, etc.